# TextMeshPro object onto TMP field in Unity Editor

Tags: unity-game-engine

What am I doing wrong that I cannot drag & drop the TMP object onto its corresponding field in the Unity Editor?

```
using TMPro;
using UnityEngine;

public class DebugText : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    private TextMeshPro _DebugText = default;

    private void Start()
    {
        _DebugText.text = "Log:";

        Application.logMessageReceived += OnLogMessageReceived;
    }

    private void OnLogMessageReceived(string logString, string stackTrace, LogType type)
    {
        _DebugText.text += logString + "\n";
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using it inside `Canvas` so use the `TextMeshProUGUI` instead.
Try this below:

```
 public TextMeshProUGUI yourtext;
```

Comment: Usually private members are hidden. `[SerializeField]` forces it to show in inspector.

Comment: [SerializeField] is to encapsulate variables.

Comment: Saad, Your solution is correct -- I'm just providing an extra explanation for why it does show (and non-interactable).

Comment: Additional information:  "TextMeshProUGUI is used when working with canvas elements. TextMeshPro is used for meshes in 3D world space."